# MvcFileUploader add/edit custom field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using MVCFileUploader https://github.com/marufbd/MvcFileUploader

This works really well for uploading images in my MVC project and associating them with an entity.

When I try to add a title field for each image that can be edited I can't get it to work.  I'm not sure if I'm approching this the correct way.  I've modified the templates in _MvcFileLoad.cshtml to have the additional field.  I can get the title input in the controller at each upload but I don't know how to send it back to the view using the implementation of this project.

This is _MvcFileUpload.cshtml, I've added autoUpload:true

```
  $('#@(formId)').fileupload('option', { 
    autoUpload: true,
    maxFileSize: @Model.MaxFileSizeInBytes,
    resizeMaxWidth: 1920,
    resizeMaxHeight: 1200,
    acceptFileTypes: @Model.FileTypes
});
```

I've added an input for title

```
<form id="@formId" action="@Model.UploadUrl" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">                    
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>

            </span>
            Title: <input name="title" required />
```

At each autoUpload I can save the title and associate it with the file and Entity in the controller.  I can't get it back to the view to edit it if the user wants to.  I tried to modify the template-download in _MvcFileUpload.cshtml

```
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
        Title: <input name="title" required />
             </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <button class="btn btn-save" data-type="What to put here?" data-url="What to put here?" >
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>
                    <span>Save</span>
                </button>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

The next issue I see is if I get the title back for editing how can send the updated input back?  There's only UploadFile and DeleteFile methods to call.

In summary I'm trying to modify this so the user can upload multiple photos and edit their titles.
MvcFileUploader uses blueimp jQuery-File-Upload.  I've looked at that documentation, there is something like what I'm asking for in the documentation for PHP but I couldn't get it to work with MVC.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your Controller method is an HttpPost, you can add a `(string title)` parameter to the method and it will grab the value from the input box automatically. Otherwise, you'll need to add a `data` property to the javascript ajax call.

For editing the title after it's been uploaded, you should have a different page. Let them view the images, and have something that will bring up a textbox with the title in an editable field and then have a submit button there. You won't have to upload the image again, just have the ID of the image in the form.

Comment: I was already able to get the title in the controller method using the `string title` parameter.  It's bringing it back and editing it that is the problem.  I was trying to avoid the approach you provide by having a different page because it's an extra step. Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: No problem. It really is the best solution. You really don't want to have to upload the files again. All it would really need to be is just a simple page, or if you want to get fancy you could do a jQuery UI messagebox.

Comment: It's not the solution I was looking for but you might be right that it's the best solution using this plugin without time consuming work.  I was going for a solution where the user could change the images and their titles on the same screen.  It looks like that would be making this plugin do something it wasn't intended for.  Thanks for your opinion. I'll have to go with the two page process until I come up with my own upload page.

Comment: Here's my opinion for why I think your approach to this is a little off. The key to what you seem to be doing is Images. That's really the root of this operation. So, if you're allowing the user to change both the Image file, AND the title, then they're actually deleting the old image and title, and creating a new one. The title is really ancillary to the image. You could change what you want to call a picture, but changing the image to fit a title isn't really the root of what I'm thinking you're trying to do.